# How do I set netmask to 0.0.0.0 (or /0)

Tags: networking

I want to use zenmap in Ubuntu 15.10 to do a local scan of all IP addresses, however, when in the `network config`, I try to set a netmask of `0.0.0.0`, it won't accept it. OK, so I thought I could just do 2 scans and put them together, but when I set it to `1.0.0.0` and then come back in, it ends up being changed to `255.0.0.0`. So,

I tried to modify `/etc/network/interfaces` and added the `eth0` interface with a netmask of `0.0.0.0`. When I restarted `networking` and ran `ifconfig`, it ended up giving me `255.255.0.0`
as the netmask. Surely, there is a way to do a local-only full network scan.

Does anyone know how?

EDIT: What I'm trying to accomplish is to scan my local network for any devices responding to

```
0.0.0.0-255.255.255.255
```

I suppose I could give my network adapter an address on each `255.0.0.0` segment and just scan them all that way, but I was hoping for an easier solution (and one that would avoid the PC from detecting itself on whatever IP is responds to in each of those 255 subnets). I guess that will be the way.

Comment: Since it wasn't clear where you're trying to *set* your netmask (in the ZenMap scan range, or the system settings), I answered on both fronts below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After all of my research, Ubuntu won't allow a netmask of anything larger than 255.0.0.0, and I couldn't find a way to trick it out of this (although it seems trivial that it shouldn't allow it), so I wrote a small script to change my IP address (starting at 1.0.0.0, then 2.0.0.0... all the way through 255.0.0.0), reset networking, run nmap from the command line and compile all of the results.

The result is a list of all IPs that are "taken" by devices on my network - exactly what I was looking for. I found a few devices out there that I was looking for and a couple I wasn't.

As mentioned, this is *not* a method for detecting rogue devices, in the security sense (that was not my objective) so it should not be treated as such for anyone stumbling upon this.

Anyway, I answered my own question and didn't want to be "that guy" so I'm following back up.

Cheers!

Answer (score 5):

> Your question is not clear on where you're trying to set your netmask.  The below will count for both ZenMap scan parameters and your system.

---

***Your System***

0.0.0.0 isn't a valid netmask for a local IP address.  The IPv4 private spaces are (in CIDR notation, thanks to [ARIN](https://www.arin.net/knowledge/address_filters.html):

- `10.0.0.0/8` (aka `10.0.0.0/255.0.0.0`) IP addresses: `10.0.0.0 - 10.255.255.255`.
- `172.16.0.0/12` (aka `172.16.0.0/255.240.0.0`) IP addresses: `172.16.0.0 - 172.31.255.255`
- `192.168.0.0/16` (aka `192.168.0.0/255.255.0.0`) IP addresses: `192.168.0.0 – 192.168.255.255`

Either use one of these, or use the one actually assigned to the network you're on.  Netmask `0.0.0.0` is not safe to use with a system IP address netmask, **nor** will it actually work as you think it will.  It's also not really a 'valid' netmask, it's a 'special' one that isn't really usable in addressing...

---

***ZenMap Scanning Parameters of Netmask to scan for***

The net mask `0.0.0.0` (in CIDR, `/0`) denotes "Every address to exist in all the universe" which is an invalid netmask for a specific IP range - you typically only see this with the IP address of `0.0.0.0`, which with CIDR is `0.0.0.0/0` denotiong the entirety of the Internet.

If you are trying to scan all local IP addresses, you're going to be working within the confines of your network.  The first place to start is by determining the netmask for your private network segment (in a home router, probably `192.168.1.0/24` which indicates only the last octet changes).

Some other common 'private IP space' scans I've used, from 'fastest' to 'most evil':

- `192.168.1.0/24` - scans `192.168.1.0` through `.255` - Fairly fast, < 10 minutes with small networks, for me.
- `192.168.0.0/16` - scans the entire 192.168.* range (which is the entire IP range for this set of private IP groups) - Takes a long time to complete
- `172.16.0.0/12` - scans the entire range of `172.16.0.0` through `172.31.255.255` (which is the entire IP range for this set of private IP groups) - takes a VERY long time to complete
- `10.0.0.0/8` - scans the entire range of `10.0.0.0` through `10.255.255.255` (which is the entire IP range for this set of private IP groups) - takes an EXTREMELY long time to complete.

Ideally, though, you *know* the address space you're scanning, and the exact netmask you want to be using.  Most home-grade private networks are `192.168.x.*`, where `x` denotes a specific octet, such as `100`, and `*` denotes any other address in the final octet.  You also typically see common home networks with a CIDR of `/24` (old style netmask of `255.255.255.0`) on these nets.

**ZenMap tl;dr**: Don't use `0.0.0.0` or `/0` for your netmask/CIDR amount.  Either use the CIDR/netmask for the private IP space you're focusing on in its entirety, or use the netmask that you know the network is using.  (DO NOT use `0.0.0.0`, you'll end up scanning the Internet!)

Comment: Sorry, I guess I wasn't clear on what I'm actually trying to accomplish. I actually want to scan my local network for "rogue" ip networks/devices. My idea to do this was to set all traffic to stay local (basiaclly what would happen if you set your netmask to 0.0.0.0) and not route it through my gateway, then use nmap to look for anything responding to the IPs 0.0.0.0-255.255.255.255 and map the network that way. The solutions you propose don't get me any closer to that end.

Comment: @mobrien118 Rogue detection usually is not as simple as you make it out to be.  In any case, you can't set 0.0.0.0 as your system's netmask, and anything hitting that entire IP space will end up going out over your router, unless you pull your Internet connection out when you do that.  If you're really trying to do rogue detection you should have other systems in place.  Your real question ***SHOULD*** have been "How to detect rogue systems on my networks" and not hte question you asked.  You can't set netmask 0.0.0.0 in either case.

Comment: What I'm trying to do is exactly, specifically what I have asked - detect the IPs of locally connected devices that have IPs between 0.0.0.0 and 255.255.255.255. My reason for wanting to do this is that we have changed network ranges several times (even before I was here). We also have several devices connected to our network that we don't actively use, but we want to clean up the network. I'm looking for anything that responds to *any* network addresses outside of our *actual* subnet so that we can clean it up.